# SQLite select query returns string with a preceeding u in python

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
#connect to the sqlite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
#create a cursor
c = conn.cursor()
#select query to return a single row
c.execute('SELECT NAME FROM T1')
#row contains the returned result
row = c.fetchone()
#print the result
print(row)
```

It prints something like --> `(u'John',)`, but I only want `John`

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the whole row, which is *always* going to be a tuple.

If you wanted to print just the first column, use subscription:

```
print(row[0])
```